# make the button in the center of screen

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

There are two buttons and I want to place them in the middle, but it always appears in the right section as the picture.
How can I solve the problem?

Home.vue:

```
<template>
  <v-container>
    <v-row>
      <v-col>
        <v-btn
          large
          router
          to="/viewRecipes"
          class="red accent-4 btn-style text-sm-right text-xs-center"
          >Explore Recipes</v-btn
        >
      </v-col>
      <v-col>
        <v-btn
          large
          router
          to="/createrecipe"
          class="red accent-4 btn-style text-sm-right text-xs-center"
          >create Recipes</v-btn
        >
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-container>
</template>

<style scoped>
.btn-style {
  color: aliceblue;
}
</style>
```

[image]

Comment: hi.  add class="text-center" to v-col like: <v-col class="text-center">

Comment: it still the problem found.
I want the two button to place it in the center.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is somehow unclear, but there are two options what do you want to achieve:

1. Center buttons inside columns

```html
<v-container>
    <v-row>
        <v-col class="text-center">
            <v-btn large 
                   router 
                   to="/viewRecipes" 
                   class="red accent-4">
                Explore Recipes
            </v-btn>
        </v-col>
        <v-col class="text-center">
            <v-btn large 
                   router 
                   to="/createrecipe" 
                   class="red accent-4">
                Create Recipes
            </v-btn>
        </v-col>
    </v-row>
</v-container>
```

2. Center buttons on the page. In order to do so you need to modify your layout a bit and place your buttons inside one column

```html
<v-container>
    <v-row>
        <v-col class="text-center">
            <v-btn large 
                   router 
                   to="/viewRecipes" 
                   class="red accent-4">
                Explore Recipes
            </v-btn>
            <v-btn large 
                   router 
                   to="/createrecipe" 
                   class="red accent-4">
                Create Recipes
            </v-btn>
        </v-col>
    </v-row>
</v-container>
```